# Run Selenium InternetExplorerDriver test with add-on (plugin) enabled

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-11

Trying to run my tests on IE. I need our plugin to be enabled.
Here is my code written in C#

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
options.UnexpectedAlertBehavior = InternetExplorerUnexpectedAlertBehavior.Accept;
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
options.EnableNativeEvents = true;

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

If run under Selenium the plugin is seen as inactive and the site asks to download the plugin.

How can I make InternetExplorerDriver enable my plugin?
Is there smth like options.PluginsEnabled = true ???
Any ideas?